# Pyside6 QScrollArea won't scroll when cursor is over items in scroll area

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyside6, pyqt6

I'm running into a strange problem with a QScrollArea and scrolling with the mouse wheel. When the cursor is over the scroll bar, the scroll wheel moves the scroll area as expected. However, if the cursor is over any of the widgets inside the scroll area, the wheel no longer works. If I put the cursor between the widgets, the wheel starts working again. I'm using Pyside6 and Python 3.9.0

I've searched pretty exhaustively and came up with no answers. I'm assuming its because the widgets inside the QScrollArea are preventing the QWheelEvent from reaching the QScrollArea, but I could not find a way to reliably fix it. I was going to brute-force it by adding an eventFilter, but I can not simultaneously get the hover/enter event and the QWheelEvent. If I attach the eventFilter to the main QDialog I get the QWheelEvent with no enter/hover for the scroll area. If I put the eventFilter on the QScrollArea, I get the latter without the QWheelEvent.

Gonna try my best to get the pertinent code below. It's a bit of a mess right now, but as soon as this problem is fixed I'll work on cleaning it up. Let me know if there is any extra information that would be helpful!

Image Examples:

Mouse wheel scroll does NOT work when over any of the graphs:

[image: Mouse wheel scroll does NOT work when over any of the graphs]

Mouse wheel scroll DOES work here:

[image: Mouse wheel scroll DOES work here]

Mouse wheel scroll DOES work here:

[image: Mouse wheel scroll DOES work here]

Main Class:

```python
class ManualCurationUI(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, max_projection_image):

        super().__init__()
        
        # CUT ALL OF THIS OUT, IT WAS JUST VARIABLE DECLARATIONS TO NONE

        self.setupUi(self)

    def eventFilter(self, q_object: QObject, event: QEvent):
        if event.type() == QWheelEvent:
            print('Scroll!', q_object.objectName())
        event.accept()

    def setupUi(self, manual_curation_window):
        self.Error = Error(self)
        self.confirmation = Confirmation(self)
        self.size_policy = self.def_size_policy(manual_curation_window)
        self.font1 = self.def_font_1(self)
        self.font = self.def_font()

        manual_curation_window.setObjectName(u"manual_curation_window")
        manual_curation_window.resize(900, 500)
        manual_curation_window.setWindowTitle("Manual Curation")

        manual_curation_window.setSizePolicy(self.size_policy)
        manual_curation_window.setMinimumSize(QSize(600, 600))
        manual_curation_window.setFont(self.font)

        manual_curation_window.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint, True)
        manual_curation_window.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint, True)

        self.gui = manual_curation_window
        self.gui.installEventFilter(self)
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(manual_curation_window)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
        self.cell_layout_horizontal = QHBoxLayout()
        self.cell_layout_horizontal.setObjectName(u"cell_layout_horizontal")
        self.cell_list_group = QGroupBox(manual_curation_window)
        self.cell_list_group.setTitle("Cells")
        self.cell_list_group.setObjectName(u"cell_list_group")
        self.size_policy.setHeightForWidth(self.cell_list_group.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.cell_list_group.setSizePolicy(self.size_policy)
        self.cell_list_group.setMaximumSize(QSize(250, 16777215))
        self.cell_list_group.setFont(self.font)
        self.cell_list_group.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.cell_list_vertical_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.cell_list_group)
        self.cell_list_vertical_layout.setObjectName(u"cell_list_vertical_layout")
        self.cell_list = QListWidget(self.cell_list_group)
        self.cell_list.setObjectName(u"cell_list")
        self.cell_list.setMaximumSize(QSize(250, 16777215))

        self.cell_list_vertical_layout.addWidget(self.cell_list)

        self.cell_list_control_horizontal = QHBoxLayout()
        self.cell_list_control_horizontal.setObjectName(u"cell_list_control_horizontal")
        self.select_all_button = QPushButton(self.cell_list_group)
        self.select_all_button.setObjectName(u"select_all_button")
        self.select_all_button.setText(u"Select All")
        self.select_all_button.setFont(self.font1)
        self.select_all_button.clicked.connect(self.select_all)
        self.select_all_button.setMinimumSize(100, 20)

        self.cell_list_control_horizontal.addWidget(self.select_all_button)

        self.select_none_button = QPushButton(self.cell_list_group)
        self.select_none_button.setObjectName(u"select_none_button")
        self.select_none_button.setText(u"Select None")
        self.select_none_button.setFont(self.font1)
        self.select_none_button.clicked.connect(self.deselect_all)
        self.select_none_button.setMinimumSize(100, 20)
        self.cell_list_control_horizontal.addWidget(self.select_none_button)
        self.cell_list_vertical_layout.addLayout(self.cell_list_control_horizontal)

        self.export_selection_button = QPushButton(self.cell_list_group)
        self.export_selection_button.setObjectName(u'export_selection_button')
        self.export_selection_button.setText(u'Export Selected Cells')
        self.export_selection_button.setFont(self.font1)
        self.export_selection_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.get_checked_items())
        self.export_selection_button.setMinimumSize(150, 20)
        self.cell_list_vertical_layout.addWidget(self.export_selection_button)

        self.cell_layout_horizontal.addWidget(self.cell_list_group)

        self.max_projection_group = QGroupBox(manual_curation_window)
        self.max_projection_group.setObjectName(u"max_projection_group")
        self.max_projection_group.setTitle(u"Maximum Projection")
        self.max_projection_group.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.max_projection_vertical_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.max_projection_group)
        self.max_projection_vertical_layout.setObjectName(u"max_projection_vertical_layout")
        self.max_projection_view = QLabel(self)
        self.max_projection_view.setScaledContents(True)
        pixmap = QPixmap(self.max_projection_image)
        self.max_projection_view.setPixmap(pixmap.scaled(pixmap.size(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
        self.max_projection_vertical_layout.addWidget(self.max_projection_view)

        self.cell_layout_horizontal.addWidget(self.max_projection_group)

        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.cell_layout_horizontal)

        self.horizontal_div = QFrame(manual_curation_window)
        self.horizontal_div.setObjectName(u"horizontal_div")

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.horizontal_div)

        self.cell_traces_group_outline = QGroupBox(manual_curation_window)
        self.cell_traces_group_outline.setObjectName(u"cell_traces_group")
        self.cell_traces_group_outline.setTitle(u"Cell Traces")
        self.cell_traces_group_outline.setMinimumSize(QSize(0, 400))
        self.cell_traces_group_outline.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.cell_traces_grid_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.cell_traces_group_outline)
        self.cell_traces_grid_layout.setObjectName(u"cell_traces_grid_layout")

        self.cell_trace_scroll_area = QScrollArea(self.cell_traces_group_outline)
        self.cell_trace_scroll_area.setObjectName(u"cell_trace_scroll_area")
        self.cell_trace_scroll_area.setMinimumSize(QSize(0, 110))
        self.cell_trace_scroll_area.setWidgetResizable(True)

        self.scroll_area_contents = QWidget()
        self.scroll_area_contents.setObjectName(u"scroll_area_contents")
        self.scroll_area_contents.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 858, 320))
        self.scroll_area_contents.setAutoFillBackground(True)

        self.scroll_area_vertical_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.scroll_area_contents)
        self.scroll_area_vertical_layout.setObjectName(u"scroll_area_vertical_layout")

        self.cell_trace_scroll_area.installEventFilter(self)
        self.cell_trace_scroll_area.setAttribute(Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_Hover)
        self.cell_trace_scroll_area.setWidget(self.scroll_area_contents)
        # self.cell_traces_grid_layout.addWidget(self.cell_trace_scroll_area, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.cell_traces_grid_layout.addWidget(self.cell_trace_scroll_area)

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.cell_traces_group_outline)
```

CellTrace class: this is what is created N times and inserted into the QScrollArea

```python
class CellTrace(FigureCanvasQTAgg):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=10, height=1.1, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        super(CellTrace, self).__init__(fig)
```

populate_traces function: takes a list of the above class and iteratively inserts them into the QScrollArea. It is located outside of the class definition and the gui object is passed in.

```python
def populate_traces(gui, cell_trace_list: list[ManualCurationWidget.CellTrace]):
    for each in cell_trace_list:
        each.setMinimumSize(QSize(0, each.get_width_height()[1]))
        each.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.Maximum, QSizePolicy.Policy.Maximum))
        gui.scroll_area_vertical_layout.addWidget(each)
```

Main Function: This is what is called to create an instance of the main class

```python
def manual_curation_gui(cell_list, cell_data, max_projection_image):
    qdarktheme.enable_hi_dpi()

    app = QCoreApplication.instance()
    if not app:
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    qdarktheme.setup_theme('dark')

    gui = ManualCurationWidget.ManualCurationUI(max_projection_image)
    populate_cell_selection_list(gui, cell_list)
    cell_traces = generate_cell_traces(cell_list, cell_data)  # ignore column one since its just time
    populate_traces(gui, cell_traces)
    gui.cell_labels = cell_list

    #app.aboutToQuit.connect(lambda: cleanup(gui))
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(app.deleteLater())

    gui.show()

    if gui.exec() == QDialog.Accepted:
        return_val = gui.cells_2_keep
        del gui
        del app
        return return_val
```

Comment: Please provide a self-contained [mre]. Also, your implementation of `eventFilter()` is **completely** wrong: 1. you shall **not** arbitrarily accept any event; 2. it **must always** return a `bool`, which means that it should return `True` if the filter should allow the target object handle the event (which means almost every time) or `False` if you want to prevent the object to receive it (the event is *filtered*).

Comment: @musicamante I'll work on the MRE. And I know its not a perfect implementation, but it doesn't change that when printing all of the events that it catches, it does not see both of the needed ones simultaneously.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear: the problem is not that it's not perfect, it's **wrong**. The very fact that `eventFilter()` is *badly* implemented *may* be the actual cause of your issue: you're accepting events arbitrarily (*any* event! and that's completely wrong! Do you realize how many event types exist and are required for proper Qt behavior?) and you're also **not** returning the value type that [`QObject.eventFilter()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#eventFilter) ***MUST*** receive. Start by doing things in the *correct* way, then see what you can do about it.

Comment: While this was not directly the solution to my problem, it did end up leading me to the solution. And it WOULD have been a problem had you not pointed it out. I'll attach an answer to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ended up solving this on my own.

First: Each item in the QScrollArea must have an eventFilter installed. I did that while adding each item to the QScrollArea. I also named them all the same thing for simplicity in the eventFilter.

For example:

```python
for each in scroll_items:
    each.installEventFilter(self)
    each.setObjectName("graph")
    self.scroll_area_layout.addWidget(each)
```

Second: The wheel event from each item in the QScrollArea needs to be forwarded to the scrollbar in the QScrollArea. This is done using the eventFilter. If the item sending the event is named "graph" and its emitting the wheel event, we send that event to the verticalScrollBar component of the QScrollArea. All other events are handled normally.

For example:

```python
def eventFilter(self, q_object: QObject, event: QEvent):
    if q_object.isGraph and event.type() == QEvent.Type.Wheel:
        QCoreApplication.sendEvent(self.scroll_area.verticalScrollBar(), event)
        return False
    else:
        return super().eventFilter(q_object, event)
```

Now whenever the mouse wheel is over the QScrollArea, it scrolls as normal. But if the mouse travels over one of the widgets in the QScrollArea, the Wheel event is forwarded directly to the scroll bar.

Comment: Notes: 1. the `objectName()` property should be *unique* (at least to its top level parent): if you need an identifier property, use a custom property name instead; 2.QScollArea already forwards wheel events to scroll bars, your issue is probably related to how events are finally handled or not, so you should probably check if `event.isAccepted()` after sending to the target, in case you want to handle it anyway *if* the scrollarea can't scroll anymore. I suggest you to take your time and dig into the official Qt sources in order to better understand how events are handled under the hood.

Comment: RE 1: Using a property now to identify the correct object.
RE 2: The QScrollArea itself is working properly. The issue was with the individual widgets inside the QScrollArea preventing the QScrollArea from getting the Wheel events. Is there a better way to go about this than what I suggested? It's working as intended now.

Comment: If you want to be sure that an event is propagated to a parent, the event must be ignored, even if it's been handled.